# is there any function in bigquery which can convert IST or PST or any local timezone to UTC

Tags: google-bigquery

I can convert time from UTC to other timestamps but am unable to find the vice versa, can anyone help on this.

```sql
select PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*SZ',  created_at,'Asia/Kolkata')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can use the following:

```
select 
    TIMESTAMP('2021-11-13 13:00:00.0', 'Asia/Kolkata'),
    TIMESTAMP('2021-11-13 13:00:00.0', 'America/New_York')
    ;
```

Pass in the string into the timestamp function and define the appropriate time zone.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp

Input represents local times for Kolkata and New York and return their corresponding UTC times.

[image: conversion]

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but my datetimes are available in IST or SGT, I need to change it in PST or EST, what you share in that case datetimes should be  in UTC ,only then it works.

Comment: To confirm, you are attempting to input a local time and get UTC as the output

Comment: Yes input is local time, and output may be other time, please help.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an image, but the original answer still takes in a local timestamp and returns it's UTC equivalent.  If this is not what you are looking for can you include an example of your expected input and output